# How can I save this image as HD as possible?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, save

I am trying to modify my song's metadata. I got this to work, but if the user has not specified an album art image I automatically draw one from a picturebox holding the album image. The returned image is really blurry- Is there any way I could make it as high definition as possible? Here is the part of my code where I handle that:

```
 if (isDir == false){
            IPicture art2 = new TagLib.Picture(new TagLib.ByteVector((byte[])new System.Drawing.ImageConverter().ConvertTo(pictureBox1.Image, typeof(byte[])))); //I make the new picture here.

            TagLib.File file2 = TagLib.File.Create(Properties.Settings.Default.NowPlayingPath);
            file2.Tag.Title = SongBox.Text;
            file2.Tag.AlbumArtists = artist;
            file2.Tag.Genres = genre;
            file2.Tag.Year = Convert.ToUInt32(YearBox.Text);
            file2.Tag.Composers = composers;
            file2.Tag.Pictures = new IPicture[1] { art2 };//I set the picture here.
            file2.Save();
            MessageBox.Show("You'll need to reload your song to continue listening to it.", "Settings saved.");
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `MemoryStream` to get image as byte array:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] buff = ms.GetBuffer();
IPicture art2 = new TagLib.Picture(new TagLib.ByteVector(buff));
```